# Не работает имитация нажатия мыши через mouse_event и SendInput

Tags: c#

В чем может быть проблема? Windows 10 x64. Сколько не пытался никак не получается организовать программный клик мыши через данные апи функции. (нажатия не происходят абсолютно нигде!)

```
static extern void mouse_event( uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint dwData, IntPtr dwExtraInfo );

static public void MouseClick()
{
    Point ptCoords = new Point();
    GetCursorPos(ref ptCoords);

    uint x = (uint) ptCoords.X;
    uint y = (uint) ptCoords.Y;

    System.IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr();

    mouse_event(0x0002, x, y, 0, ptr);
    mouse_event(0x0004, x, y, 0, ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, у вас некорректно прописаны сигнатуры для WinAPI-функций или типов. Готовые сигнатуры практически для любых функций можно найти [здесь](http://www.pinvoke.net/index.aspx). Вот рабочий пример:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct Point
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}

class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetCursorPos(out Point lpPoint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint dwData, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

    const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
    const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Point ptCoords;
        GetCursorPos(out ptCoords);

        uint x = (uint)ptCoords.X;
        uint y = (uint)ptCoords.Y;

        UIntPtr ptr = new UIntPtr();

        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, ptr);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: В том и дело, что перепробовал кучу разных способов обьявления и вызовов, предложенных из гугла, ничего не работает.

Comment: @thez, очень странно. Как вариант, антивирус у вас не установлен? Он может блочить программную эмуляцию нажатий.

Comment: Благодарю за внимание, нашел причину, действительно данные апи блокировало некое приложение (точнее игра) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/526980/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-user32-dll-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE ЗАКРЫТО!